# How to get position of file in objective-c?

Tags: macos, file, posix

```
FILE *fileStream;
fileStream = fopen(filePath,"r");
```

How to get current file position in Objective-C for Mac os x?

Comment: postion of file or cursor?

Comment: You want to know the `ftell` function? Have you considered using `NSFileHandle`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Objective-C however, that's posix stuff, you should change the tags of the question.

Comment: Your question is about C functionality so I've added proper tag. Here you have some [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/).

Comment: @MarekR, no this has nothing to do with either C nor objective-C as programming languages. The question is about system interface, from whatever language they are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ftell` to get the current file position.

Answer (score 0):

In this way?

```
  NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithCString:@"your-file" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```